# How to make a button that you must click at certain places within a certain time frame in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, project

I am trying to create a game in Visual studios using C# where you have rows of sliding boxes that you must press a key in certain locations one after the other, kinda like stacker, before the time runs out.

I am using this as the basis but unsure how to adjust the speed among making it work in the first place since the code apparently runs with no issues but I only got it where the button just gives you a message box.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O78n7apXjG8

Just asking for tips on where to go.
https://files.catbox.moe/x3wx22.zip

additional info for clarification
https://catbox.moe/c/fakpxe

```
// Project by 124
// Redid:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int _ticks;
        private object textBox1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Start();
        }
        //This should be the part that moves the button back and forth but it's not working
        int Left = 140;
        private void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          Left += 10;
            if (Left > 430)
            {
                Left = -138;
                Left += Left;
                if (Left > 140 )
                {

                } else
        {
                    button1.Left = Left;
                }
            }
            else
                button1.Left = Left;
            {
                button1.Visible = false;

                button2.Visible = true;
            }

            {
                _ticks++;
                this.Text = _ticks.ToString();
                if (_ticks == 9)
                {
                    this.Text = "Game Over";
                    timer1.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        //since the  movement button function is not working so is this one where it's supposed to give you the win but the win is there regardless
        {
            if (_ticks < 9) ;
            {

                    MessageBox.Show("good job you beat the time");
                    MessageBox.Show("You are a winner");

                }

            }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Application.Restart();
            Environment.Exit(0);

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what went wrong, but I can't run your code. Can you add a gif running diagram or running screenshots so that I can quickly understand your problem?

Comment: If you want help with your code, please post your code in the answer as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the speed among making it work：

```
Left += Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);
```

Control speed +1:

```
private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    label1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text) + 1).ToString();
}
```

Control speed -1：

```
private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    label1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text) - 1).ToString();
}
```

[image]

Updated：

Write at the top:

You can control the speed and position of the button by modifying the values of'V0' and'a'.

```
//current position       
Left += 20* _ticks+(a* _ticks* _ticks)/2;//s = v0·t + a·t²/2
```

Set the initial time value outside the timer

`private double _ticks = 0;`

Set the initial position to 0.

`double Left = 0;`

Increase by 1 every second. Because internal is 0.2, add 0.2 every time.

`_ticks+=0.2;`

[image]

Modified timer1_tick:

```cs
private void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Set acceleration
    double a = 0.5;
    //Increase by 1 every second. Because internal is 0.2, add 0.2 every time.
    _ticks += 0.2;
    this.Text = _ticks.ToString();
    //Time to stop at 9s
    if (_ticks == 9) {
        this.Text = "Game Over";
        timer1.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Game Over");
        button1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = true;
    }
    //current position       
    Left += 20 * _ticks + (a * _ticks * _ticks) / 2;//s = v0·t + a·t²/2
                                                    //When the total distance exceeds the set width on the interface, perform operations such as subtraction until the current position is less than the set value.
rtn:
    if (Left > 300) {
        Left -= 300;
        if (Left > 300) {
            goto rtn;//Use goto: Perform an iterative operation.
        } else {
            button1.Left = Convert.ToInt32(Left);//Cast double data type to int
        }
    } else
        button1.Left = Convert.ToInt32(Left);
}
```

Modified button_Click: Don’t add ‘;’ after ‘if’, it will be useless.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (_ticks < 9) //Don’t add ‘;’ after ‘if’, it will be useless.
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        button1.Visible = false;
        button2.Visible = true;
        MessageBox.Show("good job you beat the time");
        MessageBox.Show("You are a winner");

    }
}
```

Output：

[image]

Comment: If you have any questions about my code, please add a comment.

Comment: I used Visual Studios 2019  on windows form application template for C# to run it. You need to click on WinFormsApp1 file in the folder. I wanted it so I can adjust the speed based within the file itself, not something the player can control. Like for harder levels. Here is a bunch of pictures though.  https://catbox.moe/c/fakpxe

Comment: Please check my updates, and if you have questions about my code, please continue to add comments.（Is this what you said to speed it up with code?）